# dpkg-query uninstalled debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

Using below dpkg-query command to retrieve package info

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${PACKAGE}\n' dpkg
```

But how do i query a debian package (from a package file not installed package) for its Meta info like VERSION, PACKAGE using dpkg-query or any other means?

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${PACKAGE}\n' /path/to/debian/package.deb
```

Above command would fail as it expects package name instead of .deb file.

FYI:
I'm currently using as below and looking for a straight solution.

```
dpkg -I /path/to/debian/package.deb | grep -Po "^\s+Version:\s+\K.*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dpkg-deb is the native tool that works on uninstalled package files:

```
    dpkg-deb -f pkg.deb [ Version Package ... ]
    dpkg-deb -I pkg.deb [ conffiles md5sums preinst postinst ... ]
```

For options that are unique to dpkg-deb, dpkg is synonym to dpkg-deb, e.g.:

```
    dpkg -f pkg.deb Version
```

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg-query` only examines installed packages but [`apt-file`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-file) allows you to search the entire archive.  Of course, there is also the search engine at http://packages.debian.org/